# How to create rows of images

Tags: html, css, image, shopify

I am creating a certain type of image gallery for my shopify page. I have came up with the HTML for the photos and captions underneath each one of them but i am having a hard time trying to perfectly float 2 images (and underneath caption) on over each other and in a row of 9 or 10.

I am trying to get them to align like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aWTKf/1/

Here is my HTML code i came up with so far:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/eGda5OF.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/eGda5OF.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Tools" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1487" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1487">Hand tamper, string trimmer, safety glasses, 2X4, 3 foot level, yard rake with flat metal side, round nose shovel, leaf
rake, square nose shovel and hand trowel</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-2" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/t5hwGRq.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/t5hwGRq.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="1." aria-describedby="gallery-1-1488"/></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1488">(1) Select a level site or create one. Greens should not be placed in a depression or drain way. (See leveling diagrams A).</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-3" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/bT0Fekq.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/bT0Fekq.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="2." aria-describedby="gallery-1-1489" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1489">(2) Roll out green and check grade. Grade should not exceed a 2 inch rise over a 10 foot run</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-4" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/QanKcSj.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/QanKcSj.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="3." aria-describedby="gallery-1-1490" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1490">(3) Outline edge of green with weed eater, or edger <b>(always wear eye protection)</b>.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-5" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/6cnKDJj.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/6cnKDJj.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="4." aria-describedby="gallery-1-1491" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1491"> (4) Roll up green </dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-6" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/AJbuUM8.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/AJbuUM8.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Starball Cup Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1487" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1487">(5) Weed eat grass inside the outline down to the dirt or roots <b>(always wear eye
protection)</b>.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-7" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/DVir84w.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/DVir84w.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Seam Tape Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1488" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1488">(6) Rake or blow cuttings from outlined area, and cut ridges or roots if necessary. Fill any indentations</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-8" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/xVXDiO3.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/xVXDiO3.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro Green Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1489" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1489">(7) Add 8 lbs. of base for every square foot of green. Common names for the base are: #8 crusher rock with fines, 1/4 inch minus with fines, marble chips with fines. Fines are all of the smaller particles of stone down to the size of sand. Do not use pea gravel or pure sand.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-9" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/9Svblny.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/9Svblny.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Golf Games Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1490" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1490">(8) Create a gentle crown in the center for drainage with a leveling rake or 2×4 and rake the area
smooth. No indentations should be present.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-11" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/IHLRPUO.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/IHLRPUO.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro-Am Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1491" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1491">(9) Compact the base with a hand tamper, gas tamper or roller.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-12" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/ruey7dS.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/ruey7dS.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Starball Cup Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1487" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1487">(10) Check the base for levels and smoothness</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-13" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/BvejMib.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/BvejMib.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Seam Tape Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1488" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1488"> <strong> OPTIONAL: </strong> Additional paver sand can be added for smoothness or to create gentle contours in the green. Smooth with edge of level to final desired contour. </dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-14" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zt2NUWP.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/zt2NUWP.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro Green Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1489" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1489">(11) Roll out green and check smoothness and contours</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-15" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/yzEeuxC.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/yzEeuxC.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Golf Games Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1490" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1490">(12) Dig in cups with hand trowel or 4 ¼” hole cutter. OPTIONAL: If drainage may be an issue, dig 2-4 inches deeper than the length of the cup and add gravel. Top of the cup should be 1/8” below surface of the green.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-16" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/yzEeuxC.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/yzEeuxC.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro-Am Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1491" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1491">(13) Dig in cups with hand trowel or 4 ¼” hole cutter. OPTIONAL: If drainage may be an issue, dig 2-4 inches deeper than the length of the cup and add gravel. Top of the cup should be 1/8 inch below surface of the green.</dd>
</dl>
</div><div id="gallery-17" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/jJ08ueL.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/jJ08ueL.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Starball Cup Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1487" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1487">(14) If soil is too hard to dig in cups with a hand hand trowel (roots or rocks), mark hole and roll up green at hole. Then, chop up area by hole with a pick or round nosed shovel. Compact area flat and dig in hole.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-18" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/2Ppwtd0.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/2Ppwtd0.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Seam Tape Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1488" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1488">(15) After the cup is set in the ground, roll up green at hole and compact soil around the cup with the level.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-19" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/kGzroZ6.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/kGzroZ6.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro Green Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1489" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1489">(16) Roll out green and inspect contours and level cups. Cups can be leveled by stepping gently on their edges.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-20" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item"></dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/9IcvKQ9.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/9IcvKQ9.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Pro-Am Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1491" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1491">(17)
Clean and add markers or flags (optional). Surface can be raked (leaf or carpet rake), blown, vacuumed with a beater bar or hosed off or gently pressure washed.</dd>
</dl>
</div><div id="gallery-21" class="gallery galleryid-53 gallery-columns-6 gallery-size-medium">
<dl class="gallery-item">
<dt class="gallery-icon portrait"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/iv6UAEE.jpg"><img width="280" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/iv6UAEE.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Starball Cup Instructions" aria-describedby="gallery-1-1487" /></a></dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-1487">(18) To change the contours of the green over time, add a bag or two of paver sand to keep the green challenging and fun for years to come.</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS code:

```
.gallery{
    float:left;
    width:450px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left:20px;

}

.gallery-caption{
  padding-right: 200px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

If anyone could help me figure this out your help will be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: set min-height of .gallery to min-height:425px;

Comment: That worked. Perfect, Thank you so much!

Comment: Lucki Chingi, Actually it worked when i looked at the code through my browser but when i actually tried adding the code to shopify website the images stay in one line, Do you have any idea why the code is not working on there? :/

Comment: can you share the link to the shopify site?

Comment: unfortunately i'd have to give you my username and password in order to see it on shopify, it has not been deployed yet.

Comment: Does shopify not have an alternate dev url?

Comment: Would you mind trying this one: http://starpro-greens.myshopify.com/ ?

Comment: join me here on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96068/luckychingidiscussionroom

Comment: okay i am joining now

Comment: it's saying i need 20 reputations in order to speak to you through your chat room

Comment: LOL! guess i have to make it public. try now

Comment: It's still saying that i am not allowed to talk in the chatroom

Comment: whts the store password?

Comment: jubileemusik@gmail.com would you mind emailing me and i will email you the password right away?!